# ASP.Net 4.5.2 controller works but page doesn't render

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC website in which the `home/index` page invokes a call to the `Home/Candidate` page via a `button_Click()` event and an AJAX POST. The HomeController's ActionResult `Candidate()` method is invoked, but the Candidate page never renders!

I've added the `debugger;` statement in the AJAX `success` function, but it's never hit either.

I've never seen the page not render after the controller method is done; how do I figure out what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code. As a first step, check the console for errors and to check the state of your AJAX request. If `success` isn't hit then you have an error in your code somewhere, either JS or C#

Comment: add the controller method & the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I added a "debugger;" statement into the ajax "error:" function; low and behold:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

AH-HAH!